# Process after IPN is received

Tags: symfony, paypal, payum

I need to activate a user if a transaction is successful. What event should I listen after an IPN is received using Payum Bundle?

`Payum\Bundle\PayumBundle\Controller\NotifyController::doAction` doesn't seem to dispatch any event. How is this controller useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some experiments and reading more source code, I found out that we could implement desired behaviours (send email, update database) as actions and tag it with `payum.action` or simply add it to the targeted Payum context.

- [Documentation](https://github.com/Payum/Payum/blob/master/docs/symfony/custom-action-usage.md)
- [Implementation Example](https://github.com/Payum/PayumBundleSandbox/blob/0.10/src/Acme/PaymentBundle/Payum/Action/StoreNotificationAction.php)
- [Configuration per Payum context](https://github.com/Payum/PayumBundleSandbox/blob/0.10/app/config/payum.yml#L81-L88)

Configuration per action

```
services:
    acme.sample_action:
        class: Acme\PaymemtBundle\Payum\Action\SampleAction
        tags:
            - { name: payum.action, factory: paypal_express_checkout_nvp }
```

Comment: If some of the the links don't work, just need to select the correct branch from the repo and then add the line number back in